# "It is doubtless from Evola that Dugin…"

Tags: word-usage, word-order

> It is doubtless from Evola that Dugin took the central strand of his emerging worldview – allegiance to the Tradition that supposedly has its origin in a primordial heroic age.

Source: Stephen Shenfield: Russian Fascism: Traditions, Tendencies and Movements. p. 192

Is it possible to change a little the word order in the above sentence in this way:

> It is doubtless Evola from that/whom Dugin took the central strand of his emerging worldview – allegiance to the Tradition that supposedly has its origin in a primordial heroic age.

Comment: It is doubtless Evola *from whom* Dugin took... is grammatical, if you were asking about whether to say "that" or "whom".

Answer (score 2):

To me, it is perfectly clear as it was. You could change it to

> It is doubtless Evola from whom Dugin took the central strand of his emerging worldview – allegiance to the Tradition that supposedly has its origin in a primordial heroic age.

Although grammatically OK, it seems rather cumbersome or contrived to me.

Comment: I wonder if it wouldn't be better to change "it **is** doubtless" to "it **was** doubtless" when we do this transformation. Maybe both variations are okay.

Comment: Is it a rule according which you cannot say/write: It is doubtless Evola from that Dugin took…, i.e. to use the preposition before "that"?

Comment: 'It is doubtless Evola from that Dugin took…,' makes no sense at all. Not a question of a rule of grammar. I assume that it is still doubtless so we should say it is, not it was. If, however, historians once took the view that it was doubtless but no longer think it doubtless, we could construct a sentence explaining that, we would use the word 'was'.

Comment: @Bartleby Relative *that* is not permitted to stand as the immediate object of a preposition, *from that*: that construction leads the hearer or reader down the garden path of understanding *that* as the demonstrative. Youu **can** say "... *that* Dugin took the central strand of his emerging worldview *from*". However, *who* is generally preferable with persons when the relative clause is focal.

Answer (score 0):

> It is doubtless from Evola that Dugin took the central strand of his
>   emerging worldview – allegiance to the Tradition that supposedly has
>   its origin in a primordial heroic age.

**From Evola Dugin took the central strand of his emerging worldview—allegiance to a tradition that has its origin in a supposed primordial heroic age.**

Comment: But that 'de-focalizes' the emphatic assertion of Evola as the source.

Comment: Hardly. "From Evola" are the first two words of the sentence.

Comment: (though my wife agrees with you)

Comment: I'm interested in the fact that 'the Tradition' becomes 'a tradition'. The former seems to speak of a particular tradition (which one, I wonder), not just any. Also, why have the words 'It is doubtless' been removed?

Comment: Fronting *from Evola* may shift the *frame*, but it's the predicate which bears the focus. That's the point of *it* clefts: putting the desired focus in the predicate.

Comment: I think a better way to assert the factuality of something is to state it clearly *as fact*, structuring the sentence for clarity and for emphasis on the element that is most open to debate.  Are not "It is doubtless that..." weasel-words?  Do they mean exactly what they say?

Comment: I don't disagree that the cleft puts focus on the element; but it's not the only way to do so.